# Why is res.sendfile() doesn't work when I call from jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

**Issue:**
The first ajax is working properly in the `main.js`, the second one is doing its job at first look but I think there might be a bug somewhere. I can reach the `getProducts` method after I click to the button.
The `product_list.html` file should appear on the browser screen, but it doesn't.
I get no error message on the front-end or the back-end.

*This is what I noticed:* After click to the button -> F12 -> Network -> products -> I can see here a status code: 200 and the product_list.html file content as response.

In case the POST ajax call succeeds and in the case I add: `location.href = "/products";`, the browser will load `product_list.html`
I use the get ajax call because i need to pass the jwt token in the req header. (I deleted the jwt authentication parts from the code below because I narrowed down the error to the `$.ajax()`  and `res.sendFile()` relationship)

//routes.js

```
routes.get("/products", ProductController.getProducts);
```

//ProductController.js

```
var root = path.join(__dirname, '../../views');
module.exports = {
    getProducts(req, res){
        console.log("getProducts!");                 //I can see in the console
        res.sendFile("product_list.html", {root})   //It doesn't render the html
    },
}
```

//main.js

```
$("#btn-login").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:8000/login",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "username": $("#login-user").val(),
            "password": $("#login-pwd").val(),
        }),
        success: function(data){
            if ($("#login-chkbx").is(':checked')){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:8000/products",
                        type: 'GET',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("user", localStorage.getItem("user"));
                        },
                    });
                }
            }else{
                console.log("Checkbox is not checked");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What causes the issue and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: in your frontend code you do nothing with the GET products response, the backend `sendfile` as the name says it just sends the file over to the requester. Being an ajax call, it must be rendered by the frontend code.

Answer (score 1):

> file should appear on the browser screen

No it does not and it **should not**. The file should be returned to the ajax function call in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/products",
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("user", localStorage.getItem("user"));
    },
    success: function (file) {
        // The file is in the "file" variable above.
        // Do whatever you want with it. For example you can replace
        // the current page with the returned file:

        document.body.innerHTML = file;
    }
});
```

That is the whole point of AJAX - a mechanism for programmers to override the normal flow of HTTP requests that loads the response to the browser page. If it **allows** you to not load the response to the browser page it also means it **will not** automatically load the response to the browser page - because doing so will not allow you to not load the response.

If you want to automatically load the response then don't use ajax:

```
// Replace $.ajax(... with:
window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/products";
```

However, this method does not allow you to set custom request header.

Answer (score -1):

in your frontend code you do nothing with the `GET /products` response

the backend `sendfile` as the name says it just sends the file over to the requester. Being an ajax call, it must be rendered by the frontend code.

Add something like `success: response =>  $('body').html(response)`